# Getting a data file from a gallery item from a collection in Jekyll

Tags: collections, jekyll, liquid, data-files

I realize I am not a programmer, and also a beginner regarding coding but I am trying to solve a problem with a website I have built using Jekyll.
I am trying to retrieve a single item from a collection in a _data file. The code in the example pulls **all** entries into the detail.html page, I just want to show one particular item from the collection to place in the details.html page.
It comes from a picture gallery which has a link allowing the viewer to click and see a larger example of the item with all the information on the artwork.

**Here is the details.html page in the Jekyll _includes folder:**

```
<!-- Wrapper Start -->
<section id="intro">
    {% for work in site.data.work %}
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
        <div class="block">
          <img src="{{ work.img }}" alt="{{ work.title }}">
        </div>
      </div><!-- .col-md-5 close -->
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <div class="block">
          <div class="section-title">
            <h2>{{ work.title }}</h2>
            <br>
            <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics</p>
        <h5>{{ work.medium }}</h5>
        <h5>{{ work.size }}</h5>
        <h5>{{ work.frame }}</h5>
        <div class= "sold">
        <h5>{{ work.avaliability }}</h5>

            <p>{{ work.desc }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
</section>
```

This is part of the collection in the file work.json in _data folder:

```
[
{   
item1      "img": "img/portfolio/work1-big.jpg",
       "title": "Window Models",
       "medium": "Medium: Acrylic on canvas",
       "size": "Artwork size: 100cm x 100cm",
       "frame": "Frame: yes",
       "avaliability": "Avaliability: sold",
       "desc": "i am a fron on a log looking out to sea!.",
item2    },
  {

       "img": "img/portfolio/work2-big.jpg",
       "title": "The Flower",
       "medium": "Medium: Acrylic on canvas",
       "size": "Artwork size: 100cm x 100cm",
       "frame": "Frame: yes",
       "avaliability": "Avaliability: sold",
       "desc": "i am a fron on a log looking out to sea!.",
       },
     {   

     etc...
```

I would like to grab item1 in a liquid loop without other items showing on the page.them grab item2 without other items in the collection showing in the page.Then item 3 then 4 ect .......

I hope this explanation makes sense.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: I think you're using [data file](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/) and not  [collection](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/).

Comment: yes, i think that is right,  a collection appears in the front matter and the config file of a Jekyll site? sorry for my lack of knowledge.....

Comment: Yes, and that's what you have to use. Collections will offer you more flexibility by automatically creating one page per item. Data files are not appropriates to build a catalog. Read [the doc](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/), and welcome back on SO if you have other questions.

Comment: Thank you for the help!, will follow your advice !!